How to hide a specific range in matplotlib?
I want to plot a graph of electronic structure data which looks like:
    0.0000  -79.9447
    0.0179  -79.9447
    0.0357  -79.9447
    0.0536  -79.9447
    0.0714  -79.9446
    0.0893  -79.9446
    0.1071  -79.9445
    0.1250  -79.9444
    0.1429  -79.9443
    0.1607  -79.9443
    0.1786  -79.9441
    0.1964  -79.9440
.....

Every 216 rows, there is an empty row, hence I wrote code like this:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with open('Mn3PtN_bands.dat.gnu', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    
k_points = []
bands = []
current_band = []
for line in lines:
    if line.strip():  
        data = line.split()
        k_point = float(data[0])
        energy = float(data[1])-17.8059 #Fermi energy level
        
        # K_point space between X &R high symmetry 
        if k_point > 3.2801:
            k_point += 0.2
        
        current_band.append((k_point, energy))
    else: 
        if current_band:
            k_points.append([point[0] for point in current_band])
            bands.append([point[1] for point in current_band])
            current_band = []


plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
for i in range(len(bands)):
    plt.plot(k_points[i], bands[i], label=f'Band {i+1}',color='k')
plt.xlabel('k-points')
plt.ylabel('Energy (eV)')
plt.title('Electronic Band Structure')
plt.axis([0, 3.7802, -2, 2]) 
#  high symmetry points
plt.axvline(0.5000, linewidth=0.75,linestyle=(0, (5, 5)), color='r', alpha=0.75)
plt.axvline(1.0000, linewidth=0.75,linestyle=(0, (5, 5)),color='r', alpha=0.75)
plt.axvline(1.7071, linewidth=0.75,linestyle=(0, (5, 5)),color='r', alpha=0.75)
plt.axvline(2.5731, linewidth=0.75,linestyle=(0, (5, 5)),color='r', alpha=0.75)
plt.axvline(3.2802, linewidth=0.75,linestyle=(0, (5, 5)),color='r', alpha=0.75)
plt.axvline(3.4802, linewidth=0.75,linestyle=(0, (5, 5)),color='r', alpha=0.75)
plt.xticks(ticks= [0, 0.5,1.0000, 1.7071, 2.5731, 3.2802, 3.4802,3.9802],\
           labels=['$\Gamma$', 'X','M','$\Gamma$','R','X','R','M'])
#Fermi level
plt.axhline(0.0, linestyle=(0, (5, 5)), linewidth=0.75, color='r', alpha=0.75)
plt.show()

with open('bands_output.dat', 'w') as output_file:
    for i in range(len(bands)):
        for j in range(len(k_points[i])):
            output_file.write('{:.5f} {:.5f}\n'.format(k_points[i][j],bands[i][j]))
        output_file.write('\n')

The obtained figure looks like this:

As you can see, even though it isn't, it looks like there is some data between X and R points.
I want a space between two specific x points at a range inside of a plot.  How can I do that?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

you could introduce one dummy data point in your array, at the k-point corresonding to X, with a NaN for the energy value. This will create a break in the line.

I think you are trying to plot functions that has discontinuities. Since you didn't provide dataset let's create some toy data that represents a step function.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create data
x=np.linspace(0,5,10001)    
y=np.zeros(len(x))
y[x>2.5] = 1

# Plot step function
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

plt.plot(x, y, color='k')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Step Function with Range')    
plt.show()


You can deal with discontinuities by defining a range and filling with nan values in that range.
# Specifying the range within which to introduce NaN values
x1, x2 = 2.45, 2.55  # Example range to avoid plotting

# introduce NaN values for specified x range
y[((x >= x1) & (x <= x2))] = np.nan


plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

plt.plot(x, y, color='k')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Step Function with Excluded Range')
plt.show()


You should then apply it to your case for each function you are showing.

Thank you very much, just changing this is solved my problem:
K_point space between X &R high symmetry 
         if k_point > 3.2801:
             k_point += 0.2
             if k_point<=3.4802 and k_point>3.2802:
                 energy=np.nan


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Keep in mind that using for loops and if statements can make your code slower compared to vectorized manipulation of vectors/arrays. I suggest adopting the good practice of vectorizing instead of using for loops to set values.
